# Can't install Eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse, plugins, installation

I'm trying to install an Eclipse plugin for Mylyn/Fogbugz, and I get the following error when I try either EclipseBugz or Foglyn:

```
Cannot find a solution satisfying the following requirements Match[requiredCapability: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu/org.eclipse.swt
```

I'm using Eclipse 3.4.1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

what other update sites do you have enabled in your Eclipse installation?

I had similar problem when upgrading from older Mylyn, and found out that it helps to disable other updates sites. When installing new plugins, or even updating old ones, Eclipse has a tendency to contact all enabled update sites. I don't know what exactly it is trying to do, but it helped me to disable all sites except one I wanted to use.

Btw, Eclipse 3.5M6 has option to use only selected update site -- it is great help when updating/installing plugins. I cannot wait to see Eclipse 3.5 final released, just for this feature.

Comment: This worked for Foglyn, but not EclipseBugz.  I just disabled all other sites but yours.  Thanks Peter!

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse plungins require Equinox UI for dependency.Please read [Equinox installer](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox_p2_Installer)  .I hope can help you. : )

Comment: Do you mean that ALL eclipse plugins require this dependency?

Comment: No,I mean only iu package in Equinox.